# How can I make the size of my array the result of what my for loop returns?

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop

I need my array to be the size of i once iterated through the for loop. Right now it is saying that my return "array" is not found.

```
public int[] method(int[] a, int red, int yellow) {

for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) { 
     int[] array = new int[i];

        array[i] = a[i]; 


}
```

Comment: `array` needs to be defined outside the scope of the `for` loop and initialized with a size of `a.length` and not `i`

Answer (score 1):

As you have defined the `array` inside the for loop, the scope of variable array ends when the for loop ends. This is why the compiler can't find the `array` variable while returning. Try shifting `array` variable before the for loop.

Comment: I tried doing that but it does not seem to be adjusting the length accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

You should defined the array outside of the loop. Once a variable declared inside the loop it's scoped will limited to the loop.

If you think this would make sense according to your logic you could try the below code. However you will face another issue with this `IndexOutOfBoundException`. I suggest to debug and work more on your logic

```
    int[] array = null;
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        array = new int[i];
        if (a[i] >= red && a[i] <= yellow) {
            array[i] = a[i];

        }

    }
    return array;
```

Answer (score 1):

> try this.you can't return array inside the for loop as well

public static void main(String arg[]){

```
    int[] a={1,2,3,4,5,6};
    method(a,1,4);
}
public static void method(int[] a, int x, int y) {
    int[] array = new int[a.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) { 

         if (a[i] >= x && a[i] <= y) { 
            array[i] = a[i]; 

         }

      }
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array)); 
}
```

}